# model.to(device) for Pytorch Lighting

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I currently train my model using GPUs using Pytorch Lightning

```
trainer = pl.Trainer( gpus=[0,1],  
        distributed_backend='ddp', 
        resume_from_checkpoint=hparams["resume_from_checkpoint"])
    
    trainer.fit(model, train_dataloader=train_loader, val_dataloaders=val_loader)
```

Instructions are also clear for how to run test samples with trainer defined to use GPU

```
trainer.test(test_dataloader=test_dataloader)
```

and also how to load a model and use it interactively

```
model = transformer.Model.load_from_checkpoint('/checkpoints/run_300_epoch_217.ckpt')
results = model(in_data,
```

I use the later to interface with an interactive system via sockets in a docker container.

**Is there a proper way to make this Pytorch Lightning model run on GPU?**
Lightning instructions say not to use model.to(device), but it appears to work just like Pytorch. Reason for instructions to avoid a side effect?

I started reading about ONNX, but would rather just have an easy way to specify GPU since the interactive setup works perfectly with cpu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that "Remove any .cuda() or to.device() calls" is only for using with the Lightning trainer, because the trainer handles that itself.

If you don't use the trainer, a LightningModule module is basically just a regular PyTorch model with some naming conventions. So using `model.to(device)` is how to run on GPU.